# Flask: Forking Environments

Tags: python, flask

While going through the Flask Documentation at [Flask-Quick Start](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart) I came upon the following paragraph.

> Attention
>
> Even though the interactive debugger does not work in
>   forking environments (which makes it nearly impossible to use on
>   production servers), it still allows the execution of arbitrary code.
>   This makes it a major security risk and therefore it must never be
>   used on production machines.

I have searched stackoverflow, google, but I'm not able to find what are these "Forking Environments", and how can they allow execution of arbitrary code. If somebody can just point me in the right direction it'll be great!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sentence before it states:

> If you enable debug support the server will reload itself on code changes, and it will also provide you with a helpful debugger if things go wrong.

It is this *helpful debugger* that allows for execution of arbitrary code; it accepts Python code through the web and can execute that arbitrary code for you on your server.

Don't enable debug mode on production servers, it is saying.

The part about forking environments just tells you that the supplied debugger doesn't work when the process is forked (to handle requests using multiple processes, for example), but you should not be lulled into a false sense of security. Even though the debugger is broken on such environments, it is not broken *enough* to disable the Python execution functionality.

Comment: So is Flask forking itself to handle multiple requests? (Is this how generally servers handle multiple requests?)

Comment: @KartikAnand: A process can 'fork off' another child process. This can be used to hand over handling of a request, for example. Separate processes can take advantage of better concurrency if you have multiple processors or CPU cores.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!, I'm aware of fork. I'm just getting confused at the part as to whether forking is the natural way with which web servers handle multiple requests or is there something else.

Comment: @KartikAnand: it is not Flask itself that does the forking; Flask is just a WSGI 'plugin', you need a server. Flask happens to provide you with a simple WSGI server to make development easy, but in production you usually use 'bigger' iron.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation has given me something to read further.

Comment: @KartikAnand: See this [list of WSGI servers](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/servers.html) for example; there are plenty that support a forking model. The Flask Quickstart also has a section on [server deployment](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#deploying-to-a-web-server).

Comment: The question remains though - wtf is a 'forking environment'? So a web server forked a worker, and said worker starts DebugMiddleware - what does it care if it was forked? I successfully run it in my uwsgi, btw (not on production, of course).

Comment: @letitbee: A forking environment will create new child processes as needed, but if that happens during a debug session the debug state will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

It Means it's impossible to use on production servers or environment because of security issues.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.